# convert a timer to different time zone

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to convert a time value which display a duration, to another time value to another time zone please
I'm doing an auction website, i display the duration of each time, and how to ensure that if someone is in another country, it can show the duration, in his own time zone duration please

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '--this method will fetch the end date from repeater item label and update the duration
    UpdateDuration()
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateDuration()
    For Each item As DataListItem In DataList1.Items
        '--calculate the duration
        Dim duration As TimeSpan = Convert.ToDateTime(TryCast(item.FindControl("lblEndDate"), Label).Text) - DateTime.Now
        Dim label2 = TryCast(item.FindControl("lblDuration"), Label)
        '--Here is the important part: if any duration is expired then bind the grid again
        If (duration.Ticks < 0) Then


            'Grab your DateTime object (checking that it exists)'


            'Now you can output your time as you please (excluding any decimal points)'

            BindItems()


            Exit For
        Else
            '-- showing end date as last days has not arrived
            TryCast(item.FindControl("lblDuration"), Label).Text = New DateTime(duration.Ticks).ToString("dd:HH:mm:ss")
            label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd\:hh\:mm\:ss}", duration)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Days ", , 1)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Hours ", , 1)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Mins ", , 1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This following line in javascript can give you the timezoneoffset of client machines time zone with respect to UTC (For further information visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)):

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Once you know the offset you can make use of the following C# code to get the [UTC time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx):

```
DateTime UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

You can save the offset in a hidden field at client and once on server store it in a session for each user. Based on the sign of the offset you will need to decide whether to add or subtract minutes from UTC time. If the value is negative say -330 then add 330 mins to UTC datetime, and if value is positive say 20 then subtract 20 mins from UTC datetime. e.g.

```
DateTime clientTime=UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)
```

The above instructions will help you achieve what you desire. But I would also like to give you a piece of advise concerning security. **No decision should be taken based on the data that you derive from the client as this data may have been tempered.** Timezone offset that you fetch from the client should only be used to display time on their browser, but it should not affect the fact that your auction would run say 1hr from 11 AM CST. Hope you understand the risk here.

Hope this helps. Please ask for clarification if required, specially if you are not clear about what could be the risk.

Comment: I will give you a scenario, say I log into your site and I am at x timezone. Now to get some more time I would change my time zone.

Comment: So all you need to do is design your functionality keeping in mind this situation. Just ask your self a question "What if some one changes the time zone?" . And try to make your answer as close to "Even if some one changes the time zone it wouldn't affect my functionality" as possible.

Comment: oh but what i want is just that the user select it on registration only then everything is done in code behind

Comment: then it should be fine. If user changing the timezone doesn't affect.

Comment: the timezone will be set only into registration then after this the system will calculate each duration for each user in different country, i already done the duration but how to make it calculate each  duration for each country which cause me problem if you could help will be very great

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48645/discussion-between-shashank-chaturvedi-and-user3287068)